# What is the expected Doppler shift of the GPS C/A L1 PRN code duration?

Tags: python, gps

For the past few months, I have been writing an SDR-based GPS receiver (L1, LNAV, C/A).

Things are going well, and I've managed to calculate a position fix in deep space. After lots of thinking and debugging, this position fix is now 30km from my true location =).

I am now trying to track down the last sources of error. The Python application I've built involves a lot of queuing, batching, and shifting reference points to maintain optimal lock on each satellite. It is possible that there is a bug in these shifting reference points that is causing me to incorrectly timestamp each satellite's reference PRN.

That said, I'm also exploring other possibilities. One that comes to mind is that I've baked in the assumption that the PRN occupies exactly 1ms for every satellite. Intuitively, this seems incorrect, because it seems as though the Doppler effect that shifts the carrier wave would also slightly stretch and shrink the duration of each PRN chip (and the full PRN).

I am trying to think this through to come up with a story for how this would adversely affect the position fix. The pseudo-transmission-time for each satellite comes from an equation akin to:

```
Time at receiver 
- timestamp of last observed HOW timestamp 
+ PRN observations since last observed HOW timestamp 
+ fractional millisecond from PRN code phase
```

It seems the first few factors wouldn't be affected by this error - I would still observe a PRN correlation even if my replica PRN's duration was a bit off, and the PRN code phase would be adjusted to compensate. The only term that seems as though it would be affected by this error is the fractional millisecond of transmission time due to the PRN code phase. This appears to jive with the magnitude of the position error I'm observing, which is well within 1ms of error.

I am looking for feedback, and a gut check, on whether the Doppler contraction of the PRN code itself would lead to a misestimation of the PRN code phase. I am especially interested in the expected magnitude of this error if the receiver assumes a constant 1023 chips per PRN. Note that due to the extremely limited sample rate of my RTL-SDR, I am sampling at exactly double the chipping rate.